# Python list comprehension with multiple conditions

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list of strings

```
str_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

and want to add a suffix

```
suffix = '_ok'
```

when the string value is `'a'`.

This works:

```
new_str_list = []
for i in str_list:
    if i == 'a':
        new_str_list.append(i + suffix)
    else:
        new_str_list.append(i)

new_str_list
# ['a_ok', 'b', 'c']
```

How can I simplify this with a **list comprehension**?
Something like

```
new_str_list = [i + suffix for i in str_list if i=='a' ....
```

Comment: `[i + suffix for i in str_list if i == 'a' else i]`

Comment: @GhostOps gives SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @GhostOps That ain't no Python :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[i + suffix if i == 'a' else i for i in str_list]
```

Putting if after the for as you tried is for skiping values.

In your case you don't skip values but process them differently.

Answer (score 2):

Create the item according to it's value -

`[i + suffix if i=='a' else i for i in str_list ]`

Answer (score 2):

A concise option making use of fact that `False == 0`:

```
[i + suffix * (i=='a') for i in str_list]
```